# Google+ API Retrieve Profile Info

Tags: api, google-plus

My application is using Google **OAuth2** authentication with scopes ‘email’ and ‘profile’.

My Google + profile has **work** and **education** related information specified.

I’m accessing the profile info using the following URL template:

https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=<>

The returned JSON contains the ‘organizations’ element **only if** it is specified as **PUBLIC** info on my profile page. The information marked as **Only-Me** (**private**) is never returned. Why is that, having in mind that I’m accessing the profile info using ‘me’ as user identifier, i.e.:

https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me

Do I need additional authorization scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data.

[From the docs](https://developers.google.com/+/api/)